# Can an Ichthyologist identify this Canadian freshwater fish?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology, limnology

[image]

This will be very simple for a lot of you! But I been getting mixed answers about his catch. Is this a chinook salmon or brown spotted trout? Caught in Angus, Ontario, Canada. (Hwy 90 Bridge)

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Caught in a upstream river in Angus, Ontario (Hwy 90 Bridge)... Canada. This shot was from yesterday, Sunday sept. 17, 2017

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the curved caudal (tail) fin, which is more square in brown trout, this appears to be a chinook salmon. The mouth also appears to be black whereas in brown trout the mouth is white.

Sources: [Michigan Department of Natural Resources](http://www.michigan.gov/dnr/0,4570,7-153-10364_18958-387053--,00.html)